# How to fix double command problem in CodeBlocks

Tags: c++, codeblocks

I'm new to C++ and trying to learn it. When I type the #include line, I saw a list of libraries and I use the Tap on keyboard to insert the iostream to my program. Sometime it goes normal and insert only one, but sometime it double. Here the exam:
Normal: include iostream;
Double: include iosiostream

I tried to enter a new line then insert the command and it didn't double. How can I insert it without new line and without the problem?

(Sorry for missing salt in the question)

Comment: Report it as a bug? And/or switch IDEs.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try messing with the settings in CodeBlocks autocompletion.
For that you can go to:
(Settings) -> (Editor)... and then go to "Code Completion" so you can check the options for automatic library insertion. It is important to check for any settings that may be causing this duplication.
If the problem persists I would suggest updating or reinstalling CodeBlocks or using a different code editor.